# How to set from HTML template where menu is in Joomla

Tags: templates, joomla, menu

I can't find anything about this. I just made a html template and set it as a joomla template. But one important thing I can't find how to do is how to set menu from template to Joomla. Do I have to make all items of menu again in Joomla and just take css from this?

(In template is menu made from pictures, in css is hover, position etc.)

```
<nav id="main_nav">  
        <ul>  
            <li class="Item1"><a href="#"></a></li>  
            <li class="Item2"><a href="#"></a></li>    
        </ul>  
</nav>
```

Comment: You wouldn't put this direct in your template, the template is presentation only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a position in your template where module can be outputted. It's done like this:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position_name" style="xhtml" />
```

It's always a good idea to declare the position in templateDetails.xml too.
Once you're done yo can log in to your joomla backend (administrator), go to extensions > modules. Click new select "menu" from module type selection list. Then fill up the form (you can enter title for the module, select your position, pick a menu that should be rendered here etc) and you're all set.

The menu items you add to the menu selected should appear in your website.